# Yii2 user profile

Tags: yii2, profile

ok so one time i use yii2 with 1 table of user and 1 table of profile(admin,user) and was easy when i connected to the DB, but now i have 3 table of user and when i try to connect it to the DB i have problem...with the function findIdentity

```
  public static function findIdentity($id)
{

    $users = Administrador::find()->where(['id_admin'=>$id])->one();
    if(!count($users)){
      return null;
    }
    else{
      //this->password=$users->passwd;
      return new static($users);
    }
    //return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
}
```

as you can see in  $users = Administrador::find() i have the name of the table "Administrador" but i want to search the id of the others table too, help please

btw my other 2 table are "contador" and "mecanico" which the id is "id_cont" for contador and "id_mec" for mecanico

Comment: which other table do you have a raw `sql` query created? which searches correct record from the database

Comment: my other 2 table are "contador" and "mecanico" which the id is "id_cont" for contador and "id_mec" for mecanico

Comment: and `id_cont` and `id_mec` are the columns in the `Administrador` model? and with what values do you want to compare them to you have only `$id` inside the `findIdentity`  function.

Comment: No, "Administrador" only have "id_admin"

Comment: i dont get your question why are you trying to search these id's in those tables ? other than the one ueing the user identity ?

Comment: `$users = Administrador::find()->where(['id_admin'=>$id])->one();`  i have that but i want to do this too `$users = Contador::find()->where(['id_cont'=>$id])->one();` and for the mecanico too but i know you cant just add that line

Comment: Yes, you can just add that line and join the arrays. just make sure you import the libraries for those models at the top of your script.

Comment: Is it possible to have `Contador` and `Administrador` with the same ID?

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Add libraries to top of script file:

```
use someloc/model/Administrator;
use someloc/model/Contador;
use someloc/model/Mecanico
```

Then:

```
$users1 = Administrador::find()->where(['id_admin'=>$id])->one();
$users2 = Contador::find()->where(['id_admin'=>$id])->one();
$users3 = Mecanico::find()->where(['id_admin'=>$id])->one();

if (count($users1)) {
    return $user1;
} elseif (count($users2)) {
    return $user2;        
} elseif (count($users3)) {
    return $user3;
} else {
    ....
}
```

## Option 2

Use createCommand in order to use custome SQL statement.

Note: the following query joins results of two tables together.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        userid
      , field2  
    FROM
    (
            SELECT 
                t1.user_id   AS userid
              , anotherfield AS field2
            FROM 
                table1 t1

            UNION 

            SELECT 
                t1.user_id   AS userid
              , anotherfield AS field2
            FROM 
                table2 t2
    ) x
    WHERE 
        user_id = :user_id

";

$params = [':user_id' => $user_id];
$data = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->bindValues($params)->queryAll();
```